# WifiManager doesn't seem to commit changes

Tags: android, wifi

In my app, I try to connect with a specific wifi access point. However, this sets previously active networks to 'disabled'. I establish the connection by calling [`WifiManager.enableNetwork(int netId, boolean disableOthers)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#enableNetwork%28int,%20boolean%29) with setting `disableOthers` to `true`, which seems necessary to reliably establish the connection. So, after enabling wifi again manually (e.g. using the power control widget), the device won't connect with previously configured networks, which appear as 'disabled' in the networks list. I tried to circumvent this by setting each previously active network's status back to `WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED` using `WifiManager`:

```
...
List<WifiConfiguration> wifis = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
...
wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
wifiManager.updateNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
...
wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

However, even though `saveConfiguration()` returns true (success), the networks' status fields are still at `WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED`. During the operation, I get the following log message:

```
03-08 16:14:26.125: W/BackupManagerService(110): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.providers.settings' uid=10060
```

I'm aware of [this old Android bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4650), but don't know (i.e. don't hope) it is related to my problem. I'm testing with a Nexus S running 2.3.6.

**EDIT**:
Just realized that with cycling the display off and on, all settings are back to normal (i.e. networks enabled). Also different (correct) behaviour on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but instead of updating the field in the configuration, you should instead just call `enableNetwork(int, boolean)` again for each of the configurations. For example:

```
WifiManager mgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> networks = mgr.getConfiguredNetworks();
if (networks != null) {
    for (WifiConfiguration network : networks) {
        if (WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED == network.status) {
            mgr.enableNetwork(network.networkId, false);
        }
    }
}
```